# извлечь текст из textarea, вывести

Tags: javascript

```
<body style="text-align:center;">
 
<h1 style="color:green;">
    Введите текст
</h1>
 
<p id="UP" style=
        "font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>
 
 
<textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3" style="text-align: center"></textarea>
 
 
<br><button onclick="Run();">
    click here
</button>
 
<p id="DOWN" style=
        "color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>

<script>
    var el_up = document.getElementById("UP");
    var el_down = document.getElementById("DOWN");
    var str = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
 
    el_up.innerHTML = str;
 
    function camelCase(str) {
        return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(word, index)
        {
            return index == 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase();
        }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
    }
 
    function Run() {
        el_down.innerHTML = camelCase(str);
    }
</script>
```

Вообщем, нужно взять введенный текст с textarea, при нажатии button, текст виводится снизу в виде toCamelCase()
my_variable = myVariable

```
var str = 'сюда можна написать текст и он будет работь';
 
el_up.innerHTML = str;
```

И помогите исправить регулярку, она не убирает "_ "
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас в селекторе была, вот так работает:

```js
var el_up = document.getElementById("UP");
    var el_down = document.getElementById("DOWN");
    
    var el_text = document.getElementsByName('comment')[0];
    var str = el_text.value;
 
    el_up.innerHTML = str;
 
    function camelCase(str) {
        return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(word, index)
        {
            return index == 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase();
        }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
    }
 
    function Run() {
        el_down.innerHTML = camelCase(el_text.value);
    }
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
 
<h1 style="color:green;">
    Введите текст
</h1>
 
<p id="UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;"></p>
 
<textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3" style="text-align: center"></textarea>
 
<br>

<button onclick="Run();">
    click here
</button>
 
<p id="DOWN" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"></p>
```

Comment: а как пофиксить регулярку, вот на пример
"new_brand_product" не виводит newBrandProduct

Comment: Задайте вопрос по регулярке, думаю вам помогут, я не силён в них.